# sql compare columns to get result

Tags: t-sql

I have the following issue. I have products with 3 different states. Parent, Child and products which are orphans. I am setting Parents as 1, Children as 2 and Orphans as 0. I am struggling to get the Orphan to set to 0. I realise that counting the amount of Parent PLU's is where I am going wrong but I do not know how to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. (As you maybe able to tell, I am a noob and constructive criticism would be appreciated)

Kind Regards,
Jason.

[Picture of results from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM56R.jpg)

```
declare @OrderID int = 1635
declare @Store char(3) = '001'
declare @SortedBy smallint = 2

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (DetailID int, OrderID int, PLU nvarchar(35), ParentPLU nvarchar(35))

INSERT INTO @tbl (DetailID, OrderID, PLU, ParentPLU)

SELECT DetailID, OrderDetails.OrderID, OrderDetails.PLU, OrderDetails.ParentPLU
FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN PLU
ON PLU.PLU = OrderDetails.PLU
WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = @OrderID
AND OrderDetails.OrderStore = @Store

SELECT DetailID, OrderID, PLU, ParentPLU,

CASE    WHEN    (   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ParentPLU)
                    FROM @tbl
                    WHERE ParentPLU IN (SELECT PLU FROM @tbl)
                ) > 0 AND ParentPLU = '' THEN 1
        WHEN    (   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ParentPLU)
                    FROM @tbl
                    WHERE ParentPLU IN (SELECT PLU FROM @tbl)
                ) > 0 THEN 2 
        ELSE
                0
END AS ParentChild,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER   (ORDER BY 
                        CASE WHEN @SortedBy = 1 THEN OrderID END ASC,
                        CASE WHEN @SortedBy = 2 THEN DetailID END ASC
                    )  AS ID
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: try - WHERE isnull(ParentPLU, ' ') = ' '

Comment: also wrap the numbers in  's as well since they're datatype is nvarchar not int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` to get your desired result. First subquery checks for parent state, second for children. If both are null, then it is orphan

```
select 
    DetailID, OrderID, PLU, ParentPLU
    , coalesce((
        select
            distinct 1
        from
            @tbl b
        where
            a.PLU = b.ParentPlu
    )
    , (
        select
            distinct 2
        from
            @tbl b
        where
            b.PLU = a.ParentPlu
    ), 0)
from 
    @tbl a
```